# Creating UITableView in init failed

Tags: ios

I'm trying the following in Xcode 4.3.2. I've created a single view application. My `ViewController` implements `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`.

In `ViewController.m`:

```
UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 120, 100)
                                               style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tv.delegate = self;
tv.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:tv];
```

I implemented `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. It works fine, and displays "welcome" in two rows. **But If i place the `UITableView` creation in the init, then it is not working.**

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:
            CGRectMake(0, 10, 120, 100) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tv.delegate = self;
        tv.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:tv];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: I guess, it is because your view has not been loaded yet. Its still in initialize mode, so self doesn't aware about its own tableview or other subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- if you're loading from a xib file or storyboard, the initializer used is `initWithCoder:`.
- the view controller's views are not loaded until they're needed, which means `viewDidLoad:` rather than any init... method.  (Though, `viewDidLoad:` is triggered by a reference to the `view` property.)